# Cloudfront is inconsistent in serving HTTPS content

Tags: amazon-s3, jekyll, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm trying to update my blog ([jacopretorius.net](http://jacopretorius.net)) to use HTTPS. Instead of just trying this on the live version I have created a staging version to test this - [staging.jacopretorius.net](https://staging.jacopretorius.net)

My stack looks like this:

- Jekyll
- Amazon S3
- Amazon Cloudfront
- Amazon Route53

I am deploying the generated Jekyll content to an S3 bucket using the [s3_website](https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website) gem. This gem also updates the associated Cloudfront distribution. I configured the Cloudfront distribution to use my certificate and added the staging URL as a CName to the distribution. Lastly I added 2 aliases from Route 53 to point to the distribution, one for IPv4 and one for IPv5.

Everything seems to be working as expected, except for some bizarre behavior I don't understand. All the pages seem to be served via HTTPS, except for https://staging.jacopretorius.net/archive/. I thought this might be because the URL doesn't have an extension, but https://staging.jacopretorius.net/about/ is being served correctly. This is happening consistently in both Chrome and Safari.

When I dump the headers using curl the headers seem to indicate that the one URL (the /about/ one) is always a Cloudfront miss.

```
curl -s -D - https://staging.jacopretorius.net/archive/ -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 63941
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 20:11:29 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 19:25:42 GMT
ETag: "289e13a6c58bd46dfa55d22cd5e0d1a6"
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 51
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 0a955f76d9c9f3e49899a6eb7a411ec5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: avt5CRfDiCwEU7TlhvUoCQKsR_jGB_2M_w5zy5mmDoFhogtS4doaQA==
```

```
curl -s -D - https://staging.jacopretorius.net/about/ -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3757
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 20:12:24 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 19:25:42 GMT
ETag: "fa3a2f263be864012dc5a792d651a46c"
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 fc8718fc654846d5ff65e1100874c1fc.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: btONKzglg2FkPo9ycWiqQz-aBQ85sugrwTES14TfmedmBQNPPim_Jg==
```

The [Cloudfront documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html#LinkFormat_TrailingSlash) seems to indicate that there is no problem with this kind of URL, it simply says that you should be consistent (which I am).

I'm really stumped on this. My only thought here is that somehow Cloudfront is caching the /archive/ response and the first time it tried to retrieve that asset it didn't get the response it expected, but that doesn't quite add up since the content is there, it's just not HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `https://staging.jacopretorius.net/archive/` page is being served as secure when I load it. What makes you say it isn't being served secure exactly? If you type in `https://` and see the page content then the page is being served over HTTPS, but if you don't see the green lock icon the browser doesn't think the page is fully secure. You need to click the little (i) icon in the Chrome browser address bar and see what the actual issue is. The browser wouldn't be displaying any page content at all if it had an issue with the SSL certificate on that page.

I see a message in Chrome that not everything on the page is secure. I think that's because the search form on the page has an `http://www.google.com/search` target. Try changing that to `https://www.google.com/search` (and clear the CloudFront cache for `/archive/` after making the change).

Comment: Mark! You're my hero!  Thank you!  (I would say that Chrome isn't being very helpful in this context - it didn't tell me why it thought the site was insecure, and curl was just noise.  How confusing!)